# textbox values unremoveable until the textbox is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

can anyone help me how to do this? i want to do is the `textbox` values is removable or cant be change until the `textbox` is clicked.Can anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please be aware that this may cause problems for users (especially those with mobility impairments) who do not have or who are unable to use a mouse. It may also annoy power users who are used to tabbing between inputs in a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the readonly attribute to your input ...

```
<input type="text" id="input_a" readonly />
//or
<input type="text" id="input_a" readonly="readonly" />
```

... and then onClick remove it

```
document.getElementById('input_a').removeAttribute('readonly');
//or
document.getElementById('input_a').readOnly = false;
```

The readonly attribute differs from the disabled attribute in that the value is still submitted with the form and, crucially, does not disable click (prevent the event being raised) on the element.

Comment: You will want to use readonly and not disabled as the click event is not dispatched on disabled controls (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input). Both are boolean attributes, which means that the value can be optionally omitted with the same effect.